# TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I turn my code to class, it now return some error. that i dont know what is this. i tested already without wrapper into class, the code working. what is this exactly?

> ```
> TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable
> ```

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const options = require('../config/database');

class Mysql
{
    pool;

    createPool(options)
    {
        this.pool = mysql.createPool(options).promise();
    }

    async execute(query, parameter)
    {
        try 
        {
            const [rows,fields] = this.pool.execute(query, parameter);

            return [rows,fields];
        }catch(e)
        { 
            console.log(e.code);
        }      
    }
}

const client = new Mysql;

client.createPool(options);

(async () => {
  const [rows] = await client.execute("SELECT * FROM media");

  console.log(rows);
})();
```

Comment: What do you think square brackets mean?

Comment: This `this.pool.execute(query, parameter);` is most likely not returning an array so you can't do `const [rows] =` [Array Destructuring](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/array-destructuring-in-es6-30e398f21d10/)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica execute exactly from mysql library return array `[rows,fields]`, i edited my question.

Comment: @fortunee but if i dont wrap into class, it return. exactly mysql library return array `https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper`

Comment: should `const client = new Mysql;` become `const client = new Mysql();` ?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to change your `[square brackets]` with `{curly}`

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh if no constructor inside class. its no need parentheses. parentheses to pass paremeter into constructor method.